# scraping google custom search result with PHP

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm using simple_html_dom.php

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');

    $songName = '再见青春';

$dom = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/cse?q='. $songName .'&cx=partner-pub-4291153493758949%3A9692445719&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8&ad=w9&num=1');

$firstRow = $dom->find('#gs-visibleUrl-long')->plaintext;

echo $dom;
var_dump($firstRow);

?>
```

$dom is ok, but I want to dive in the DOM, it doesn't work. The `$firstRow` returned NULL. Am I doing this scrapping wrong?

The Dom and error is here http://daysof.me/chrome_lyric/lyric.php

Comment: i've tested it and no you cannot scrape it this way, not even using curl, it needs javascript to do so, use this to find out why `$element = $dom->find('html', 0); echo $element->plaintext;`

Comment: @Ghost I don;t get it, so any other method to scrape? I just need an url from the result.

Comment: actually, thats the part i haven't tried before, maybe you can try an alternative. phantom.js, but this is a major shift, anyway i wish you good luck

Comment: Note that scraping is agains their terms of use, and performing lots of queries this way might get your server blocked.

Comment: @GolezTrol I want to scrape a site but the site's search function is suck, they use custom search in their, that seem the best way to get accurate result, but now I got know it's against google TOS, wow.. any alternative?

Comment: Well, if it is a script that runs once or a couple of times, then it's probably not a big deal. I thought you were trying to wrap GCS  to build a search feature for your own website. Google would probably be able to detect that by the number of requests you made.

Comment: @GolezTrol I see. So now I'm like at the end of my afford.. any other way? I googled a lots but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: @Ghost will phantom solved the request limit of GCS?

Comment: @user3522742 sorry but i can't really help on this matter, most of the time i help here really was always thru `DOMDocument+Xpath` and that library `simple-html-dom and ganon`, that suggestion (phantomjs with casperjs) was just a shot in the dark, since i haven't used it yet, just an alternative to look into

Comment: I found that bing api limit is not mention, 7 request per second from an IP, good to try?http://www.bing.com/developers/s/APIBasics.html#_Using_the_API